playing audio when page opened
Hi all iam trying to play audio when page opened or launched i have used window.onload but the audio still not playing although it's playin on blur and focus
I have tried window.onload <body onload> to play the audio once launched but not playing also the alert is popingup but the sound not working
 window.onload = function() {
            // This function will be executed when the page finishes loading
          birdAudio.play();
            alert('The page has finished loading!');
        };


HTML 5 specifies that browsers should not automatically play media on page load without any user interaction. It's part of a design to prevent annoying sites from automatically playing media that may conflict with existing audio/video and it's arguably a good thing. See this thread for more details.

cant begin to express how bad of an idea this is to auto play music. Should always make it an option to play. Not to mention you haven't even considered accessibility issues for doing this.

The whole audio-on-page-load makes me have 1990s style flashbacks. The horror.

I don't think you need javascript to do this as HTML 5 has a built in audio system as such :
<audio controls autoplay mute>
    <source src="audio_file.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

You could remove the autoplay command from the first line to NOT make it automatically play just so you are aware.  With the controls command, they can click to play it if they decide to do that, instead of forcing them to listen to it each and everytime the page loads.
But you could put something like this in, and just replace the link to the mp3 file you wish to play on page load.  If it is in the same directory as the html file, it should just play, however if you have directory nesting or offsite files, make sure you have the proper rights to those locations if you find problems getting them to play.
Although, similar as has been mentioned by others, its not best practice to play an audio file automatically on page load.  Perhaps you should build an options tab to let them click to turn it on if they make the concious choice to want to listen to it automatically everytime.
UPDATE - as per @h0r53 's suggestion, add the mute command after autoplay so that it will give the user an option to unmute to play if they wish.

i have noticed thise exception Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first., i want the audio to be played when the page is launched

It seems that that error is indicating you can't do an autoplay without user interaction, which basically means you can't do it automatically.  If you remove the autoplay part does it show the controls and can you click play and it will play?

@RehamSafarini that error is literally what I mentioned in a comment under your question. The DOM does not allow playing media before a user interacts with the page. It's a design in HTML5. You need to use something like autoplay mute and let the user click a "play button" or equivalent to start the media.

Yeah I have noticed the behaviour

Good point on the addition of mute, I'll update that info to suggest using mute.

if muted how come the sound will be out ?

Are you able to click the play button, that should play the audio.   But I know your goal is to get it to play it when its done loading and is probably just a sound effect instead of a looping audio file, but with current standards this is how it is.

exactly, this the point

Alas although it use to be possible to do this, they made it not possible now using standard methods.
